# Prove $r \circ f = s \circ f \implies r =s$ holds for a surjection $f$.

Tags: proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

Frankly I'm not convinced what I have is technically correct so I was hoping to get some verification.

---

Suppose we have functions $f:A\rightarrow B$, $r:B\rightarrow C$, and $s:B\rightarrow C$.

Assume that

$r \circ f: A \rightarrow C = s \circ f : A \rightarrow C$

$\iff \forall a \in A, (r \circ f)(a) = (s \circ f)(a)$.

And also that we have a function $f$ that is surjective.

Thus $\forall b \in B, \exists a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

$(r \circ f)(a) = (s \circ f)(a)$

$\iff r(f(a)) = s(f(a)) $

$f(a) = b \in B$

> Is this all I need to write the next line?

Therefore, $r(b) = s(b), \forall b \in B$.

> Does this actually follow?

$\implies r=s$.

It follows that surjectivity is the necessary and sufficient condition for the hypothesis to be true.

Comment: Your argument is correct. In short what you've done is this: you've picked an arbitrary $b$, and shown (correctly) that $r(b)=s(b)$. That's all you need to do.

Comment: Oh, I guess it didn't occur to me that the $b \in B$ was arbitrary and that was why it could be generalized to all of $B$